# Rake aborted! Don't know how to build task 'deploy'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rake

I am trying to deploy changes to my staging server (on heroku) and I keep on getting the following error message:

```
    Matthews-MacBook-Air-2:iGiveMore WorkWell$ rake deploy staging --trace
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'deploy'
/Users/WorkWell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:49:in `[]'
/Users/WorkWell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:142:in `invoke_task'
/Users/WorkWell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/WorkWell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/Users/WorkWell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/Users/WorkWell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/WorkWell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/Users/WorkWell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/Users/WorkWell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/WorkWell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/WorkWell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-10.0.3/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/WorkWell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/WorkWell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

please help!

Comment: It's been a while since I've used Heroku (so this is not an answer), but I remember deployments being a simple matter of pushing a Git branch to the remote repository hosted on Heroku ... no rake involved.

Comment: Specifically, this error means there is no `task :deploy` block in your Rakefile. You can build such a task that will deploy to heroku, but as everyone else is saying, a git push generally suffices.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku deploys don't use rake.  You do `git push $REMOTE $REF:master`, where $REMOTE is the name of the git remote, or a git URL, and $REF is master, HEAD, or some other commit you want to push.

Also, if you're pushing the current HEAD, you can just do `git push $REMOTE master`, or, depending on your git config, `git push $REMOTE`

Comment: While you can push to other branches, your target branch should always be *master* if you want the commits to be compiled into the slug. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler

Comment: Right.  I should edit my answer, I meant to write something slightly different...